# Ambiguous Class Template Conversion

Tags: c++, templates, type-conversion, copy-constructor, copy-initialization

How would one add a template constructor to the class so that copy initialization from complex to complex is performed explicitly and without ambiguity? Is there a solution that is compiler and C++ version/standard agnostic? Is there an approach that only requires definition of a constructor without an additional operator overload?

I included the template copy constructor and operator overload (last two methods defined in the class) but the compiler gives me the following message.

```
Compilation error
main.cpp: In function ‘void testTemplateConstructor()’:
main.cpp:74:27: error: conversion from ‘complex<float>’ to ‘complex<double>’ is ambiguous
      complex<double> cd = cf;
                           ^~
main.cpp:35:5: note: candidate: complex<T>::operator complex<X>() [with X = double; T = float]
     operator complex<X>(){
     ^~~~~~~~
main.cpp:29:5: note: candidate: complex<T>::complex(complex<X>&) [with X = float; T = double]
     complex(complex<X>& arg) {
     ^~~~~~~
```

This is the test case being utilized.

```
void testTemplateConstructor() {
     complex<float> cf{1.0f, 2.0f};
     complex<double> cd = cf;
    
     Assert(cf.real()==cd.real(), "Real parts are different.");
     Assert(cf.imag()==cd.imag(), "Imaginary parts are different.");
}
```

```
template <typename T> class complex{    
    
    private:
    typedef complex<T> complexi;
    T real_;
    T imag_;
    
    public:
    complex(){
        real_ = 0;
        imag_ = 0;
    }
    complex(T a, T b){
        real_ = a;
        imag_ = b;
    }
    complex(T a){
        real_ = a;
    }
    complex(complex<T>& comp){
        real_ = comp.real_;
        imag_ = comp.imag_;
    }
  template <typename X>
    complex(complex<X>& arg) { 
        real_ = arg.real_;
        imag_ = arg.imag_;
    }
   
    template <typename X>                  
    operator complex<X>(){
        return complex<T>();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution I was looking for, this works with the C++11 standard and compiler versions as old as x86_64 gcc 4.7.1 and clang 3.4.1. The only difference apart from the use of static_cast is the use of getters.

```
using namespace std;

template <typename T> class complex{    
    
    public:
    typedef complex<T> complexi;
    T real_;
    T imag_;
    
    public:
    complex(){
        real_ = 0;
        imag_ = 0;
    }
    complex(T a, T b){
        real_ = a;
        imag_ = b;
    }
    complex(T a){
        real_ = a;
    }
    complex(const complex<T>& comp){
        real_ = comp.real_;
        imag_ = comp.imag_;
    }

    template <typename X>
    complex(const complex<X>& rhs){
        real_ = static_cast<T>(rhs.real());
        imag_ = static_cast<T>(rhs.imag());
    }

    T real() const {
        return real_;
    }
    T imag() const {
        return imag_;
    }

  
};
```

Answer (score 1):

> so that **copy initialization** from complex to complex is performed explicitly and without ambiguity? Is there a solution that is compiler and C++ version/standard agnostic?

Yes, in this particular example, you can add a low level `const` to the parameter of the ctors.

```
template <typename T> class complex{    
    
    public:
    typedef complex<T> complexi;
    T real_;
    T imag_;
    
    public:
    complex(){
        real_ = 0;
        imag_ = 0;
    }
    complex(T a, T b){
        real_ = a;
        imag_ = b;
    }
    complex(T a){
        real_ = a;
    }
    complex(const complex<T>& comp){
        std::cout<<"nornal version";;
        real_ = comp.real_;
        imag_ = comp.imag_;
    }
   template <typename X>
     complex(const complex<X>& arg) { 
        std::cout<<"template version";;
        real_ = arg.real_;
        imag_ = arg.imag_;
    }
   
   
};
void testTemplateConstructor() {
     complex<float> cf{1.0f, 2.0f};
     complex<double> cd = cf;
    
    
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/8Gb485naj)

Comment: Do you even need both of them? Aren't they doing the same thing?

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow OP didn't mention in the question that completely removing one of them is also an option. Otherwise, doing that is an obvious way of removing the ambiguity. Anyway i have added that point at the end of my answer though i do think OP is already aware of that.

Comment: I just wonder if there is any case where you need one of them and the other won't work and vice versa. Is there any case where you would need both?

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Most probably not. But C++ never ceases to surprise. So there is possibility of those cases.

Comment: I had already tried adding explicit, but still get this error when adding explicit to both and an even longer error message when only adding to the copy constructor. main.cpp:74:27: error: conversion from ‘complex<float>’ to non-scalar type ‘complex<double>’ requested
      complex<double> cd = cf;

Comment: @DarnocEloc Don't add `explicit` to both the ctor and the overloaded `operator` at the same time. Just add to any one of them at a time as shown in my answer. See [demo](https://onlinegdb.com/Lidcq8P68)

Comment: @DarnocEloc See the [working demo1](https://onlinegdb.com/51cle7WJXl) and [working demo2](https://onlinegdb.com/Tt0aJbv-y). The same links are also given/added in the answer.

Comment: As I stated previously, neither of these approaches work for me, what compiler and standard are you using/referencing?

Comment: @DarnocEloc They work in GCC & Clang with C++17 last i checked. That is why i gave the demo links so that people can see it for themselves that they work.

Comment: It is a compiler issue, according to godbolt.org, it works with x86-64 gcc 11.1 and beyond, the latest clang version x86-64 clang 14.0.0 did not work. Clang gives message <source>:43:22: error: no viable constructor copying variable of type 'complex<double>'
     complex<double> cd = cf;.

Comment: How were scenarios such as this dealt with in earlier versions?

Comment: It works in all compilers and all C++ versions if you add a low level const in the templated constructor. See [working demo with const](https://godbolt.org/z/j1szPGEv3). Note in the above demo link i have added a `const` and highlighted it with a comment so that it is easy to spot. I have added the same in my answer. Check out my updated answer.

Comment: Basic error on my part not adding const to copy constructors. For some reason still not working in the original **stepik** compiler I was working in.

Comment: Can you comment on the specific effect of the const keyword in this case?

Comment: @DarnocEloc By adding `const` the parameter of the ctors become *lvlaue reference to `const` object* meaning they can now be bound to temporaries of the respective types[demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/mCbHVUXRI5uc7v3Y). Before when there was no `const`, the parameters were simple *lvalue reference to non-const object* which means before they could not be bound to temporaries and you'll get error saying the same. [demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/57oRl8DjM2t5U5Gn). Also, note that you should remove the `operator complex<X>()` otherwise you can have infinite recursion.

Comment: But a move constructor could be used to bind the temporaries to r-value references.

Comment: @DarnocEloc Your class template `Complex` doesn't have any move constructor because you've defined a copy constructor for your class. So the move ctor cannot be used in your case since there is no move ctor available for your case.

Comment: Hypothetically of course, I said a move ctor could be used.

Comment: @DarnocEloc Yes then a move ctor can be used.